# How to use react suspense with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I havn't found any documentation or examples to explain this but from what I understand to use suspense you must add a Suspense boundary to the parent component and remove async/await from the child component and lazy load it. But when removing async/await it breaks types because everything is a promise.

For example changing `await (await fetch('some-api')).json();` to `fetch('some-api').json()` gives the error `.json is not a function`.

Values also cannot be typed because `const data: MyData = fetchData()` will error because `fetchData` returns `Promise<MyData>`.

With Suspense

```
function Parent() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <Child />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function Child() {
  const data: MyData[] = fetchData(); //Error: Type 'Promise<MyData[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'MyData[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more
  return (
    <div>{data.map(d => <p>d.name</p>)}</data>
  );
}
```

Before Suspense

```
function Child() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<MyData[]>([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
     async function loadData() {
         setData(await fetchData());
     }

     loadData();
  }, []);

  if (!data.length) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <div>{data.map(d => <p>d.name</p>)}</data>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using suspense with lazy loading is meant to be used for code splitting, not data fetching. If you want to use it in this way your code need to throw an error before the fetching is complete, and reset itself when it finishes. But it's not recomended to be used for fetching outside of SSR frameworks like Next.js and Relay etc.

Comment: Suspense for data fetching is experimental. Check more here https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Comment: ok thank you, I am using Next.js, but still don't see how to add the types.

Comment: @Tasos there is also https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense

Comment: Yes @Lance but as it says in the description it is not ready for data fetching yet

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** - `fetchData`'s type signature would need to be just `Data`, not `Promise<Data>` (because it's actually `fetchData(): Data with effect ReactSuspense` or `fetchData(): Data throws Promise<Data>`)

#### The details

Suspense doesn't make async code block, it *hides the async* behind indirection. Effectively, it's trying to introduce preemptive scheduling (where the runtime can stop your code at any time and switch to running a different bit of code) into a cooperatively scheduled environment (where the runtime won't stop your code until your code hits a point you've explicitly annotated with "and I yield the floor").

How it works at a hand-wavey level:

- Run your component `<Child />`
- Inside of `Child` you call `fetchData`
- `fetchData` must *signal* React in some way "hey, I need you to interrupt `Child` because we need to wait for some condition before `Child` can be resumed".

  - `throw` and `catch` are the only signaling mechanism that JavaScript provides
  - So `fetchData` *throws* a promise and React's runtime *catches* it.  This means that `Child` stops executing (it's preempted).  React adds a `then` listener to `fetchData`'s promise that will put `Child` back on the queue of items to be "rendered" later.
  - Later, that promise is fulfilled.  React re-render's `Child`. `fetchData` needs to have *cached* the result of the promise so that when it is next called with the same arguments it will return the *cached* results **synchronously**.
  - This means that the type of `fetchData` is ***not*** (as you would expect) `Promise<Data>` but instead ***JUST*** `Data`.

Comment: ok get it, thank you, and any suggestions please on best way to cache large data?

Comment: Generally, just close over a `Map<SomeKey, SomeResult>` - for a `fetchById` it's `Map<Id, Data>` - for a broader `fetch` it's going to be some kind of _normalized_ `Request` (so that `fetch({ x: 1, y: 2 })` and `fetch({ y: 2, x: 1 })` both find the same `Data` even though the keys are not in the same order, for example - the particulars depend on the semantics of the service that `fetch` is talking to.)